# Clickhouse JDBC driver class name

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, clickhouse

Has anyone used Spring JDBC with Clickhouse? What is the driver class name?

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=<what is it?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it could be it, even though it doesn't look like any other driver class names that I have seen.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also lighter and faster alternative to the official driver version - [clickhouse4j](https://github.com/blynkkk/clickhouse4j). (fork of the official driver with some improvements)

You can use it like this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=cc.blynk.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Driver was renamed due to moving vom yandex to clickhouse.com.

**Clickhouse Driver**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver
```

See https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc

Also note Java Client and JDBC Driver MVN dependencies changed as well:

**Maven Clickhouse Java Client**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
    <!-- or clickhouse-grpc-client if you prefer gRPC -->
    <artifactId>clickhouse-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.2-patch11</version>
</dependency>
```

**Maven Clickhouse JDBC Driver**

```
<dependency>
    <!-- please stop using ru.yandex.clickhouse as it's been deprecated -->
    <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
    <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.2-patch11</version>
    <!-- use uber jar with all dependencies included, change classifier to http for smaller jar -->
    <classifier>all</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Starting 4.0.0 yandex packages will be removed and be non functional!